# chckbox and select usage in state of reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello friends first of all I have a small app which I develop by using react js and I am new. most of things works but I have stuck in 2 point first is checkbox when I click checkbox it goes true but it is out of row objects when ı check it out on react-dev-tools (I hope you guys understand what ı mean when you run the code:) ) second problem I want to use react-select when I select it gives me error and not update constraint and datatype when ı check in state
thanks for your help

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select'

const constraintEnums = [
  { label: "NULL", value: 1 },
  { label: "NOT NULL", value: 2 },
];

const dataTypeEnums = [
  { label: "BOOLEAN", value: 1 },
  { label: "CHAR", value: 2 },
  { label: "VARCHAR", value: 3 },
  { label: "TEXT", value: 4 },
  { label: "INTEGERS", value: 5 },
];

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    tableName: '',
    rows: []
  }
  handleCheckbox = () => {
    this.setState({ pkChecked: !this.state.pkChecked })
  }
  handleTableNameChange = e => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
  }
  handleChange = idx => e => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    const rows = [...this.state.rows];
    rows[idx][name] = value;
    this.setState({
      rows
    });
  };
  handleAddRow = () => {
    const item = {
      pkChecked: false,
      columnName: "",
      dataType: "",
      constraint: "",
      length: ""
    };
    console.info(`item:`, item);
    this.setState({
      rows: [...this.state.rows, item]
    });
  };
  handleRemoveRow = () => {
    this.setState({
      rows: this.state.rows.slice(0, -1)
    });
  };
  handleRemoveSpecificRow = (idx) => () => {
    const rows = [...this.state.rows]
    rows.splice(idx, 1)
    this.setState({ rows })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ paddingTop: '25px' }}>
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row clearfix">
            <div className="col-md-12 column">
              <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="tableNameInput">Table name</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  name="tableName"
                  onChange={this.handleTableNameChange}
                  className="form-control"
                  id="tableNameInput"
                  aria-describedby="tableNameHelp" />
                <small id="tableNameHelp" className="form-text text-muted">Enter the name of the table you want to create.</small>
              </div>
              <table className="table table-bordered table-hover" id="tab_logic">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th className="text-center"> # </th>
                    <th className="text-center"> Key </th>
                    <th className="text-center"> Column Name </th>
                    <th className="text-center"> Data Type </th>
                    <th className="text-center"> Constraint </th>
                    <th className="text-center"> Column Length </th>
                    <th />
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  {this.state.rows.map((item, idx) => (
                    <tr id="addr0" key={idx}>
                      <td>{idx}</td>
                      <td>
                        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox mr-sm-2">
                          <input
                            type="checkbox"
                            className="custom-control-input"
                            id="customControlAutosizing"
                            value={this.state.rows[idx].pkChecked}
                            onChange={this.handleCheckbox} />
                          <label class="custom-control-label" for="customControlAutosizing">Primary Key</label>
                        </div>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <input
                          type="text"
                          name="columnName"
                          value={this.state.rows[idx].columnName || ''}
                          onChange={this.handleChange(idx)}
                          className="form-control"
                        />
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <Select
                          options={dataTypeEnums}
                          name="dataType"
                          value={this.state.rows[idx].dataType || ''}
                          onChange={this.handleChange(idx)}
                        />
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <Select
                          options={constraintEnums}
                          name="constraint"
                          value={this.state.rows[idx].constraint}
                          onChange={this.handleChange(idx)}
                        />
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <input
                          type="text"
                          name="length"
                          value={this.state.rows[idx].length || ''}
                          onChange={this.handleChange(idx)}
                          className="form-control"
                        />
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <button className="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm" onClick={this.handleRemoveSpecificRow(idx)}>Delete</button>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  ))}
                </tbody>
              </table>
              <button onClick={this.handleAddRow} className="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
              {
                this.state.rows.length != 0
                  ? <button onClick={this.handleRemoveRow} className="btn btn-danger float-right">Delete Last Row</button>
                  : null
              }
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "out of rows"? Also, what error is thrown when changing the `Select`?

Comment: when ı check state in react-dev-tools, State

pkChecked:
true
rows:
Array[1]
0:
{…}
columnName:
""
constraint:
""
dataType:
""
length:
""

pkChecked:
false
tableName:
"" pkChecked suppose to be in row array but it is out of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your checkbox:

You set state directly to the `pkChecked` state, not the attribute in your rows. A fix for that is to do it like you have done with your `handleChange` function:

```
handleCheckbox = idx => e => {
    const rows = [...this.state.rows];
    rows[idx].pkChecked = !rows[idx].pkChecked;
    this.setState({
      rows
    });
}
```

Also `input[type=checkbox]` does not take a `value` prop for its checked state in React, but instead it uses a `checked` prop:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked={this.state.rows[idx].pkChecked} {...} />
```

---

Regarding the `Select` component:

The `onChange` prop on the `Select` component does not send an event to the handler, but instead the value and an `action` object which itself as a string representation of the action and the `name` of the `Select` component in it. Based on that information I would recommend you create an extra `handleSelectChange` function for the `Select` components:

```
handleSelectChange = idx => (value, { name }) => {
    const rows = [...this.state.rows];
    rows[idx][name] = value;
    this.setState({
      rows
    });
}

<Select {...} name="dataType" onChange={this.handleSelectChange(idx) />}
```

---

Also a minor thing I would recommend: Use `item` instead of `this.state.rows[idx]` in your `render` method when you map over your rows. You already have the current row in the `item` variable, you don´t need to fetch it again from state.